# Scaling Spotify client on Linux HiDPI display

Tags: linux, scaling, spotify, high-dpi

On my Linux Mint 20 Cinnamon I just installed Spotify like this:

```
curl -sS https://download.spotify.com/debian/pubkey_0D811D58.gpg | sudo apt-key add -
echo "deb http://repository.spotify.com stable non-free" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/spotify.list
```

which is the most universal installation procedure as per [their page](https://www.spotify.com/us/download/linux/).

---

I was however disappointed by the scaling on my extra high DPI laptop UHD display.

So, the question is, since this application does not auto-scale, how do I force it to a certain scale ratio?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution was rather straightforward, that is creating a desktop entry and editing it with your favorite text editor, and adding this argument with some suitable number as a scale, in my example, there is 2.5, but you can use whatever you find suitable:

```
--force-device-scale-factor=2.5
```

---

So, the resulting desktop file could look like this:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Name=Spotify
GenericName=Music Player
Icon=spotify-client
TryExec=spotify
Exec=spotify --force-device-scale-factor=2.5 %U
Terminal=false
MimeType=x-scheme-handler/spotify;
Categories=Audio;Music;Player;AudioVideo;
StartupWMClass=spotify
```

---

Source:

- [community.spotify.com](https://community.spotify.com/t5/Desktop-Linux/Feature-Request-Fix-HiDPI-scaling-in-linux/m-p/2257705/highlight/true#M3028)

Comment: OP is using Linux Mint 20 Cinnamon, in which case finding exactly which `spotify.desktop` file to edit can be tricky.

Instead, if you use the built in mint menu, right click it and choose `Configure`, then under the `Menu` tab choose `Open the menu editor` and find `Spotify`. Click `Properties` and add the `--force-device-scale-factor=2.0` flag to the command text-box.